# Having trouble with Intellisense seeing struct members

Tags: c#, struct

I am setting up two queues, one to hold received 8-byte values, and one to hold 8-byte values to send.  The sending and receiving will occur in a separate thread (or two) which is started in the App.xaml.cs file of the WPF solution I have created.  I want the queue to contain STRUCT describing those 8-byte values.

I really didn't think this STRUCT thing was going to be a big deal.  I have been using STRUCT forever in C code.  But for some reason the STRUCT definition seems to be working (no complaints from VS 17), and the STRUCT instantiation seems to be working, but the initialization of STRUCT fields is not being recognized.  ????  see the code sample below.

I have tried:

```
// define the structures
public struct ReceiveStruct {
  byte[] deviceName;
  byte functionCode;
  byte MSBbyte;
  byte LSBbyte;
}
public struct SendStruct {
  byte[] deviceName;
  byte functionCode;
  byte MSBbyte;
  byte LSBbyte;
}

// instantiate the two structures that I want
public ReceiveStruct receiveStruct;
public SendStruct sendStruct;

// initialize the structure fields
receiveStruct.deviceName = 'abcde';    // HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES
                                       // Intellisense does not recognize
                                       // these fields???  It does not
                                       // list "deviceName" for example 
                                       // after
                                       // the "dot" after 
                                       // "receiveStruct".
                                       // receiveStruct.functionCode = 3;
.
.
.

// instantiate the queues
Queue receiveQueue = new Queue();
queue sendQueue = new Queue();

// populate the queues
receiveQueue.Enqueue(receiveStruct);
sendQueue.Enqueue(sendStruct);
.
.
.
```

I figured I would initialize the struct fields for the first time to not violate the "by value" rules for structs, and then happily change these fields as my code progressed and load up the queues in order to be processed elsewhere as a FIFO, feeding other LIST, actually, to then be acted on and logged.  No big deal.

But I can't get past the dumb struct initialization!!!!

Comment: Make the fields explicitly `public`. The public-by-default-for-struct-members rule does not exist in C#. Be wary of keywords that are the same between any two languages; the semantics are often very different.

Comment: Try following : public ReceiveStruct receiveStruct = new ReceiveStruct();

Comment: and not doing so then makes the fields private, and not "seen" by Intellisense?  that is weird.  I can see how that might affect their visibility elsewhere in the program, but immediately after instantiation???  I will try this.

Comment: @TonySimkus C++ is the joker, not C#. C++ has default-public access on struct members as a concession to backwards compatibility with ANSI C. I'm a little taken aback by your idea that member access should be different in proximity to a constructor call. For how many lines of code do you think the compiler should arbitrarily violate the access explicitly specified by the author of the class? Ten lines? Twenty? And for heaven's sake why? When I say a member is private, I want it private, and I expect the compiler to honor that.

Comment: @TonySimkus Or are you just suggesting that Intellisense should offer you options the compiler won't let you use? IMO that's a mistake, for the same reason: The internals of the class are none of the caller's business.

Comment: Also be aware that a C# struct is a value type, as opposed to a class, which is a reference type. Enqueueing and dequeueing results in copying of all struct members.

Comment: Ed... of the options you gave me for covering up my ignorance, I will take the second one.  It's Intellisense fault!

Comment: Clemens... I am okay with copying the members, since there will be very few of them, and they are small.  But, I think you are suggesting that I define a class and not a struct, and handle it that way.  Well, if I have to...